# How to reach Windows filesystem from Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, file-management

I have a VM running Ubuntu in Windows 7. Is it possible to open a file that a have on the windows filesystem in a program that is run in the VM? Or do it Have to use dropbox or something like that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a shared folder. Make sure you have the VBoxAdditions installed in your Ubuntu guest and create a new shared folder by choosing `Devices->Shared Folders` of the VBox window of the running guest. Afterwards, you should be able to mount the folder in Ubuntu using the following command:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf FOLDERNAME /mnt
```

(I assumed the name of the share you just created is `FOLDERNAME`). You should be able to see all files of the directory in `/mnt`. Find more information [here](http://virtuatopia.com/index.php/VirtualBox_Shared_Folders#Accessing_a_Shared_Folder_from_a_Linux_Guest) or [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=virtual%20box%20shared%20folders).

Answer (score 1):

You can't access any files outside of the VM's virtual hard drive. You can still use a USB drive or any cloud storage service for file transfer between Windows and Ubuntu running on the VM.